# Allow 'empty' classname in SASS for generating utilities

Tags: css, sass

We are working on creating some utilities and have previously given them a prefix when used of 'u:' so in the HTML is would look something like the following:

```
<div class="u:bg-red"></div>
```

Today we wanted to drop the prefix and just use 'bg-red' in this example, but SASS doesn't allow an empty classname.

This is how we are currently generating:

```
.u\: {
    @include group();
}
```

(the included group is a mixin that contains all of the utilities)

The actual properties are setup in a mixin and look as the following:

```
&bg-red {
    ...
}
```

The reason why I don't just add the dot in the mixin is because we also create responsive utilities using the following:

```
.u\@lg\: {
    @include screen-large() {
        @include group();
    }
}
```

I basically want to be able to do the following:

```
. {
    @include group();
}

.\@lg\: {
    @include screen-large() {
        @include group();
    }
}
```

But... SASS doesn't allow an empty classname. We've tried all sorts of escaping and tried to be clever but no success!

Closest is to do:

```
.\ {

}
```

But this results in a space before the property.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all your use cases, but would something like this work for you?

```
@mixin group($prefix:null) {
  .#{$prefix}bg-red {
    ...
  }
}

@include group(); // To get .bg-red

@include screen-large() {
  @include group(u\@lg\:); // To get .u@lg:bg-red
}
```

Comment: Looks like it could! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Lovelock let me know if I missed a use case. (: